# Microsoft Powerpoint 2007 background music

Tags: audio, microsoft-powerpoint

I am trying to put an audio background to a presentation, but I need it embedded, so I don't need the audio source file when I do the presentation.

I have searched around and the official answer is that there is a limit in size for the audio file for which it will be linked, not embedded. By default that is 100kb, but one can get that as high as 50MB. I tried different audio files, even 10kb in size, but it will only link it, so if I delete the audio file, it will not play it anymore.

To me, this seems like a defect. Is there a solution/workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some versions (yours included) will only embed WAV sounds; other sounds get linked.

Try converting your sound to WAV.